# C# List Any method - bug or misunderstanding

Tags: list, c#-4.0

**Snippet 1**

```
var list1 = new List<int>();    
list1.Add(100);    
var temp = "ABC";    

var result = list1.Any(x => x == 200 || temp == "ABC");
```

**Snippet 2**

```
var list1 = new List<int>();    
var temp = "ABC";    

var result = list1.Any(x => x == 200 || temp == "ABC");
```

In snippet 1, I'm expecting result = false but it gives me true, but it gives expected result = false in snippet 2.

Is this a bug or am I expecting it to do something that it's not supposed to?

I know it obviously it makes sense to move the temp = "ABC" condition outside the Any method.

Comment: *Why* do you expect the result to be false for listing 1? Do you think there is any element x where *either* x is 200 *or* temp is "ABC"? I think there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `.Any` the List must have elements and at least one of it must statisfy the conditions of `Any`. Your conditions are *ALWAYS* true - due to `||temp == "ABC"` - the only thing that makes the first snippet return false is the empty list.

The first returns  `false` because the list is EMPTY not because the condition is false.

[Enumerable.Any Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ```
> Return Value
> Type: System.Boolean
> true if any elements in the source sequence pass the test in the specified 
> predicate; otherwise, false
> ```

No elements in list == no one passes == false.

The `.Any()` overload w/o predicate tells it a bit more explicitly:

[Enumerable.Any Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697(v=vs.110).aspx)

> ```
> Return Value
> Type: System.Boolean
> true if the source sequence contains any elements; otherwise, false.
> ```

Conceptually: 
You could see the `.Any(x=>x ==200 || temp == "ABC")` as

```
var list1 = new List<int>();    
list1.Add(100);    
var temp = "ABC";  

bool foundOne = false;
foreach( var i in list1)
{
    if (i == 200 || temp == "ABC")
    { 
        foundOne = true; 
        break;
    }
}
// what value has foundOne here if the list has 0 elements or 1 elemnt?
```

Comment: the first code snippet returns true even if there are no matching items in the list and the second snippet returns false because there no items at all.

Comment: @Shyam yes-  because you formulated the predicate for Any to be always true regardless of what is in the list. This: `.Any(x => x == 200 || temp == "ABC")` with a `var tmp = "ABC";`  defined ist the same as `.Any(x => dont care about x at all  OR TRUE)` which is true IF there is at elast 1 element in the list.

Comment: @Shyam: see addon to answer

Comment: @Shyam: "even if there are no matching items in the list" - what makes you think there are no matching items? When the value of `x` is 100 and the value of `temp` is "ABC", what do you think the value of the expression `x == 200 || temp == "ABC"` is?

Comment: @JonSkeet I do know what the value of the expression is, what I'm asking is how would it evaluate if it's inside List.Any method as a predicate. Although it doesn't make sense to return true, I will go with Patrick's answer as it's the best explanation so far.

Comment: @Shyam: I don't see how you can say that you know what the value of the expression is, but then say that it doesn't make sense to return true. There is an element of the list (call it `x`) for which the expression `x == 200 || temp == "ABC"` returns true. Your predicate is matched, so `Any` returns true. You haven't given a clear explanation for why you expect it return false.

Comment: I was expecting Any method to be more smart and only evaluate if there are any items that match the condition(s) relevant to the list, temp == 'ABC' is irrelevant for the list and it should have just ignored that. I agree adding that irrelevant condition as part of the list filter expression is a mistake to begin with.